# What are the best optics to use, to make a laser project a uniform line?

Tags: optics, laser

I need to make a laser project a line rather than a spot.

I will probably be using a copper vapour laser.

What are the best optics and techniques I can use do get a line that has a uniform brightness along it's length with a 'fan' angle of about 10-30 degrees.

I would prefer not to use rotating mirrors to do this, as it would create a modulation that would interfere with the device I am making.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this by putting the laser light into a cylindrical lens (or a cylindrical lens telescope, or a prism pair if you want it line-like but collimated), but this won't be uniform brightness along the line. Depending on the application, you might just be able to make the beam large before or after doing this and aperturing the light, as the light near the maximum of the beam will be to first order constant in intensity. Other than that, you could probably achieve more uniform intensity with diffractive optics like an SLM or a DMD.